# React context menu & watch for prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys Im trying to build React context menu component,
Here is how my code looks currently:

```
import { css } from '@emotion/core';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState }  from 'react';


const styles = {
  root: css({
    position: "fixed",
    padding: "5px 10px",
    background: "white",
    zIndex: 999,
    outline: "none",
    boxShadow: "0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24)",
  }),
};


export default function ContextMenu(props) {

  let event = props.show;

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const contextEl = useRef();



  const handleBlur = () => {
  }

  if(event) {
    return (
      <div tabIndex="0" css={styles.root}  ref={contextEl} className="context-menu" onBlur={handleBlur}>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
```

And here is how outer component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ContextMenu from '../components/ContextMenu';

function Home(props) {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(false);

      // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
      useEffect(() => {
          document.addEventListener('contextmenu',onClickfn);
      });

    const onClickfn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCount(e);
    }

  return (
    <div >
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <button>Click me</button>
          <ContextMenu show={count}> 
        asdasdasdasd
         </ContextMenu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What Im trying to achive is event is passed to inner component to focus element, and then set state that context menu is visible and when user click outside (blur event will be active and I should hide context menu) then again when user click on outer component I would like to detect change I again show component

Is there any way how I could achieve something like that in React ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/vkbansal/react-contextmenu/blob/master/src/globalEventListener.js) implementation:

```
import { MENU_SHOW, MENU_HIDE } from './actions';
import { uniqueId, hasOwnProp, canUseDOM } from './helpers';

class GlobalEventListener {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = {};

        if (canUseDOM) {
            window.addEventListener(MENU_SHOW, this.handleShowEvent);
            window.addEventListener(MENU_HIDE, this.handleHideEvent);
        }
    }

    handleShowEvent = (event) => {
        for (const id in this.callbacks) {
            if (hasOwnProp(this.callbacks, id)) this.callbacks[id].show(event);
        }
    }

    handleHideEvent = (event) => {
        for (const id in this.callbacks) {
            if (hasOwnProp(this.callbacks, id)) this.callbacks[id].hide(event);
        }
    }

    register = (showCallback, hideCallback) => {
        const id = uniqueId();

        this.callbacks[id] = {
            show: showCallback,
            hide: hideCallback
        };

        return id;
    }

    unregister = (id) => {
        if (id && this.callbacks[id]) {
            delete this.callbacks[id];
        }
    }
}

export default new GlobalEventListener();
```